# Using the If statement inside the while loop for storage and time while a command is running in the terminal (that fills up disk space)

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to create a script that checks if the disk is full, if not keep the command running until you hit 60%, if you don't hit 60% stop the loop because the disk is full; Use the if statement to calculate the time inside the while loop. For example: if time > 5 min break the while loop

Any suggestion on how I may do this?

```
USED_SPACE=$(df /tmp | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $4}' | sed 's/%//g')
i=0
```

1.) Start the command that wont stop

2.) Now run the while loop:

```
while [ #{USED_SPACE} -lt 60 ]; do
    sleep 30
    ((i++))
    $i
    if [[ $i > "5m" ]]; do 
        break
    fi
done
```

3.) Next end the command that wont stop. Execute it

Thank you

```
Current
/dev/mapper/vg00-tmp           4184064   37072   4146992   1% /tmp
```

I want the output to be 60% like this:

```
/dev/mapper/vg00-tmp           4184064   37072   4146992   60% /tmp
```

Comment: `#{USED_SPACE}` should be `${USED_SPACE}` Is that in the real code or a copying error?

Comment: What do you mean by wanting the output to be like that? Your script doesn't print anything.

Comment: The line `$i` will get an error. It will try to execute the counter as a command. I think you mean something like `echo $i`

Comment: `$i > "5m"` doesn't make sense. And `if` is followed by `then`, not `do`. Please paste your code into shellcheck.net and fix the basic syntax errors.

Comment: Disregarding other issues, you have the quotes backwards in `$i > "5m"`.  In general, and among other reasons, quotes are used to prevent the shell from interpreting characters and to prevent word splitting.  It is never necessary to quote a string like `5m`.  `"5m"` and `5m` will be treated identically by the shell.  But a string like `$i` is (possibly) treated differently than `"$i"`.  In short, you should quote `"$i"`, but you do not need to quote `5m` .  Unless you have a reason not to, always quote your variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not certain of parts of your question, but for the size and time counter you can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

used_space=$( df /tmp | awk 'FNR==2 {print substr($5, 1, length($5)-1)}' )
echo "$used_space"

time_counter=0
while [[ "$used_space" -lt 60 ]]
do
    sleep 30
    used_space=$( df /tmp | awk 'FNR==2 {print substr($5, 1, length($5)-1)}' )
    (( time_counter += 30 ))
    if [[ "$time_counter" -gt 300 ]]
    then
        break
    fi
done
```

Details

- instead of using a series of commands to extract the percentage value from `df`, I use `awk`.
- `FNR==2`: will only process line 2
- The `substr` removes the last character from field $5, which is xx%, where xx is the value you want.
- The `echo` is just to see the value, remove it as needed.
- The `while` will run until used_space is >= 60.  But to get the `while` to stop, you have to extract the used_space value again inside it.  You did not do that.
- For the time counter, I add 30 in every loop, so when it reaches 300 (5 minutes * 60 sec), it breaks.
- So this code will stop if used_space >= 60, or if it has been running for more than 5 minutes.

You can add the command start and any output code you desire in this base script.

Note it is good practice to put your code in https://www.shellcheck.net/ to check your syntax.  I do it every time I post an answer here.